# Trying to insert some data and an incrementing number as id (oracle db)

Tags: sql, oracle, insert

I'm trying to insert data in my table1 that looks like this : id, value1, value2..

id being the primary key. I have an insert statement looking like this:

```
insert into table1 (id,value1,value2..)
    select ([*],value1, value2 ..) 
    from table2
```

Now I want to have an incrementing number starting at 1 to be inserted into id from table1. What do I need to write into * to make this work?

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you using??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle 12C, you can define `id` as a generated column.  [Here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/identity-columns-in-oracle-12cr1) is an article on the subject.

In earlier versions of Oracle, I define a sequence:

```
create sequence table1_sequence;
```

You can use it directly in the `insert`:

```
insert into table1 (id,value1,value2..)
    select table1_sequence.nextval, value1, value2 ..
    from table2 ;
```

Or, what I normally do, is create an `insert` trigger to set the `id` automatically for *any* insert.

If you are only loading the table once, you can do the quicker-and-dirtier:

```
insert into table1 (id,value1,value2..)
    select row_number() over (order by ?), value1, value2 ..
    from table2 ;
```

The `order by` is in case you want the ids in a particular order.

Or, you can simply use:

```
insert into table1 (id,value1,value2..)
    select rownum, value1, value2 ..
    from table2 ;
```

Comment: Hi thanks so far. I only need to do this onces. What do I need to put into those brackets "(order by ?)" ? I don't have it in a specific order so I guess I ignore the order by but whats supposed to be at the question mark ?

Comment: @JohnDoe . . . In Oracle, you can use `order by NULL` if you don't care about the actual ordering.

Answer (score 1):

> There is no such thing as "auto_increment" or "identity" columns in
>   Oracle as of Oracle 11g. However, you can model it easily with a
>   sequence and a trigger:

```
 CREATE SEQUENCE id_seq START WITH 1;
```

**Trigger definition:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER table1_tir 
BEFORE INSERT ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT id_seq.NEXTVAL
  INTO   :new.id
  FROM   dual;
END;
```

> IDENTITY column is available on Oracle 12c:

```
create table table1(
    id NUMBER GENERATED by default on null as IDENTITY,
    value1 VARCHAR2(10),
    value2 VARCHAR2(10)
 );
```